# I can't get sonic pi on the raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, sonic-pi

I can't seem to download sonic pi on my raspberry pi 4. I have tried going to the sonic pi website https://sonic-pi.net/ and downloaded from there but it always comes up with an error. I have also tried typing *sudo apt-get install sonic-pi* and that still comes up with an error. everywhere I look, they all say the same thing but it never works.

Comment: "An error" and "never works" doesn't give us any information that could help troubleshooting. What commands did you run, and what output did you get? Be specific.

Comment: this is the error that pops up
Sonic Pi Boot Error

Apologies, a critical error occurred during startup:

 Critical error! - Could not boot Sonic Pi Server.

Please consider reporting a bug at
http://github.com/samaaron/sonic-pi/issues

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue (https://github.com/sonic-pi-net/sonic-pi/issues/2755#issuecomment-826180395).

Here is the linked comment attached with instructions:

"As seen in many other raspberry pi labelled issues here, the version of Sonic Pi that is distributed with Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS, (v3.1) is one that was built outside of our control, and as a result is also partially broken.

The best way to get Sonic Pi working on your system is 1) to make sure that you have the most recent version of Raspberry Pi OS (from January this year) loaded on your Pi, 2) Make sure that Sonic Pi v3.1 is uninstalled, and 3) to download Sonic Pi directly from our website: (https://sonic-pi.net)"

Comment: I have downloaded form the sonic pi website but the same error comes up. i have run "sudo apt update" multiple times and downloaded and uninstalled sonic pi multiple times as well.